# Linking jQuery plugins to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have already checked plenty of issues that have a similarity to my error however it still seems to not work.

I am sure I declared those plugins in the right order but that haven't shown any progress at all.

I did try comparing it on my codepen account (both scss) and the (compiled to css) and it works on codepen BUT not in sublime text. I found out that it is not calling my main.js for some reason. Did i do something wrong in my codes? but it works on codepen which makes it very confusing on my part as to where it went wrong

**[Codepen SCSS](https://codepen.io/UmaruHime/pen/boyGRo)**

**[Converted to CSS](https://codepen.io/UmaruHime/pen/dVEyRo)**

this is my html code in **sublimetext** which is the same codes as the converted to css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Crown Royale Dental</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" href="js/main.js"></script>

  <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <h2>Clinic Facilities</h2>

    <div id="projectsApp">

        <div class="projects" :id="project.ID" v-for="project in projects" :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + project.bImage + ')' }" v-on:click="selectProjects(project.ID)">
            <h3 class="beforeTitle"> {{ project.category }}</h3>
                <div class="info">
                    <h1 class="fadeTitle"> {{ project.category }}</h1>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            <p class="backArrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
        </div>

        <div class="selectedArea">
            <h1 :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + highlightedContent.bImage + ')' }"><span>{{ highlightedContent.category }}</span></h1>
                <div v-html="highlightedContent.copy" class="copyArea fadeIn"></div>
        </div>

    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

the main.js and style.css codes are quite long but it is the same as the codepen codes. does anyone have any idea what caused this? why isn't the js not working?

here is a screenshot of what im seeing on sublimetext localhost with inspect element
[image: Sublime text output]

Please see the codepen link for what the supposed output should look like.

Big thanks to those who can lighten me up. I am still trying to figure out what caused it. checking similar cases that might work.

Comment: Put you all scripts files in before the body end and also call script with src=" attribute not with href

Comment: @HardenRahul do you mean to say put all scripts inside body?

Comment: Yes I definitely meant that

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the javascript using `href` instead of `src` in the wrong way. Try using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: This seems to fix the height of the {{Project Category}} that we are seeing, however, it is still unable to view the images and contents i added. I cannot also click it

Comment: The initial question had to do with the main.js not being loaded. If you need to ask something different, then you have to ask a new question. I am not familiar with how vue.js works, so I cannot answer what you are asking.